# get physical media type of ethernet adapter using c++ on linux

Tags: media, ethernet

I am using this code to get some info about ethernet adapters.

```
for(i = 0; i < nInterfaces; i++)
    {
        struct ifreq *item = &ifr[i];

        if(ioctl(sck, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr[i]) >= 0)
        {
            if (!(ifr[i].ifr_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK))
            {
                printf("Name : %s\n", item->ifr_name);
                printf("Media : %s\n", (ifr->ifr_flags)&IFF_UP ? "Up" : "Down");
                printf("Bandwidth : %d\n", item->ifr_bandwidth);
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I determine the media type of adatper? For example wireless, bluetooth, ethernet(802.3) etc.?

Prashant

Answer (score 0):

If we believe this site: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl7_netdevice.htm, then there is a value in the ifr_flags member called IFF_PORTSEL which is "Is able to select media type via ifmap.".

Comment: Could you please guide me a little to get it?